# Add custom attributes to folder, currentFolder, or files in CKFinder

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

We are developing a custom connector since we have to integrate CKEditor and CKFinder into our CMS (PeopleSoft). Since the CMS doesn't fully conform with normal file system regarding paths (i.e. /root/folder/file.fil), we would like to add a custom attribute to the folder object in the json response. For example, we would like to add the attribute `contentid` to each folders to identify each folder especially that it's possible to have the same folder/file name inside a folder. Then we would want to append that attribute when commands such as GetFolders and GetFiles so that we can use it for identifying the correct parent folder.

Comment: What CKFinder version and which connector do you use?

Comment: CKFinder is version 3.4.1. The connector we are using is a custom one we developed for PeopleSoft's CMS. We based its code from PHP and ASP.